# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on trivial code

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, exc-bad-access

This is the code:

```
UITabBarController *tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
tbc.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:ptlc,cvc,gvc,nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tbc animated:YES];
[tbc release];
```

This is the last part of the code in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:. When selecting the row the UITabarController shows fine, but when hitting the "back" button on the UINavigationController, the program crashes after a second without printing any description on the console. The debugger just points me "Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"." on this line:

```
 int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

On "main.m". Incredibly, removing the last line solves the problem. ptlc cvc and gvc are controllers which I first alloc inited and that I release after the last line of this code sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it myself using the profile tool "zombies". It showed me that an UIImage was receiving a release message after being deallocated. It was because I was using the same UIImage for two different UITabBarItems on the UITabBar.

Answer (score 0):

since theres nothing visibly wrong with that code, memory wise; it leads me to believe it's occurring because you shouldn't use a `UITabBarController` as a viewcontroller in a `UINavigationController` stack. From the Apple Documentation on `UITabBarController`:

Before creating a tab bar interface, you need to decide how you intend to use it. Because it imposes an overarching organization on your data, there are only a handful of appropriate ways to use a tab bar interface:

- Install it directly in your application’s main window.
- Install it as one of the two root views in a split view interface. (iPad only)
- Present it modally to display some data that requires its own mode-based organization.
- Display it from a popover. (iPad only)

Comment: UITabBarController can be used inside UINavigationController for sure. I've seen it done a lot of times. What I know is that it can't be done the other way (navigation inside tabbar).

Comment: @Hallucynogenyc  Quoted from [`here`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH102-SW2): "Although a navigation controller can be embedded inside a tab, the reverse is not true. Presenting a tab bar interface from within a navigation interface is potentially confusing for users." Tab bar in navigation stack is not recommended.

Comment: Deepak is right, as I explained above as well. but since this is a bad access problem, a good hint is to turn on NSZombie and see where the problem is happening.

Comment: I saw this being done in the Standford iPhone Application Development course (CS193P). I can believe that this usage is not recommended, but it's a must in my project. Still, this is not the point of the question. It shouldn't throw the error and it should show me where the error was produced, instead of telling me that it was produced in main.m, shouldn't it?

Comment: it generally means something is being called after it has been released, turn on NSZombie like i said (a search for xcode 4 NSZombie should get it), and see where it is crashing out. Might also want to try the Xcode 4 Analyze feature